# Civic overheating and hoses popping

Tags: honda, civic, overheating

My Honda Civic LX 2002 overheating me again this morning going to work. I already changed the thermostat, put in a new radiator, water pump and got it flush. Now I noticed that my hoses even popping too, because I had to change 4 hoses on it so far and now I gotta change another hose because it pop on me. I wonder what else I need to do so it could stop overheating on me?

Answer (score 5):

Have the engine compression tested or leak down tested as I suspect the problem you are describing may be the result of a failed cylinder head gasket as it sounds like pressure from the combustion chambers is escaping into the cooling system.

Comment: Also a test to consider would be to test the presence of exhaust gas compounds in the coolant. There are tests that do this, and they may be more sensitive to small cylinder head gasket leaks, but if the hoses are popping, it may be the leak is so large that even a compression test might detect it.

Answer (score 0):

I had my head gasket chekk and everything is okk with it. No mix with oil n cooler. I even have like two mechanic chekk it out n they told me the same. They only guessing that since I put everything in news. That my hoses might need to be changes.

Comment: Signs of coolant in the oil cooler won't always be present when the head gasket has failed, especially if the failure is between a combustion chamber and a coolant gallery.  Have the two mechanics who've confidently said it isn't head gasket performed leak-down tests?

Answer (score 0):

If it has the 4 cylinder Engine I would have to say Head Gasket Also. The best way to check the Head Gasket is to perform Leak down test with the Radiator cap off and see if the coolant is bubbling. I have seen multiple Honda Engines pass the Block test and still have a blown Gasket/Warped Head.